# How to make predictions with a decision tree on a dataset without a target value?

Tags: python

Every tutorial I have found about machine learning includes testing an algorithm on a dataset that has target values and then it finds how accurate the algorithm is by testing its predictions on the test set.

What if you then receive all of the data except for the target value and you want to make target value predictions to see if they come true in the future?Every tutorial I have seen has been with data that they already know the future target value predictions.

Comment: This is way off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decision tree is a supervised algorithm. That means you must use some target value(or lable) to build the tree(dividing node's value based on information gain rule).

Comment: What does this have to do with OP’s question? Am I missing something?

Comment: OP was asking why all tutorials he/she'd seen on machine learning require you to have target/label data to train model for and @chenn had correctly pointed out that decision tree that OP particularly mentioned is a supervised learning algorithm and so requires target values to train the model on. There's of course a whole bunch of unsupervised learning tools as well: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/unsupervised_learning.html, so this is what OP should use instead.